# Most commonly forgotten thing to do when programming/web developing

Tags: learning, web-development, programming-practices

Does anyone else have that one thing they always forget to do when programming or developing a website?

Personally mine is forgetting to include the Doctype in a website...the amount of time i have spent ages fixing/adding/hacking around with CSS to fix IE problems and it turns out to be the F'in Doctype declaration!!!

Comment: I would tell you mine, but I forgot what it was...

Comment: Please explain, how does this follows the 6 guidelines to asking questions?

Comment: What's being asked here or is this just a poll? Why distinguish between "programming" and "web developing"? Isn't web developing a form of programming?

Comment: Yes, but i know some people dont class writing basic HTML as "programming" so i thought i'd make it more obvious

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Checking the site at different resolutions gets me some times.

Something that my co-worker seems to forget all the time is to remove his Firefox debug statements.

Some things that I've learned (the hard way) to always check:

- All validation on a web form
- Making sure query strings work and
  can't be manipulated easily
- Javascript works in all supported
  versions of IE and FireFox

Answer (score 0):

Forgetting to run the unit tests before committing the code.  And getting publicly flogged for breaking the build.

Answer (score 0):

Set correct permissions on my sitemap (asp.net).  I have forgotten to set the roles up correctly and to have them match the web.config a bunch.

More generally, just testing as alternate users/roles when changing something.  As a developer I'm always the Admin, I change something, it works.  I deploy, oops someone from Role X calls and tells me feature X is no longer available.